# Sync Android app with other devices

Tags: android, software-development, api, web-server

I develop an Android app for private use of a few users. And I need to sync the data between them.

It uses SQLite as DB.

Is there a simple, free API that allows me to sync data between the devices with a webserver DB that I could set up or with a free cloud service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Backendless](https://backendless.com/). It is free for low traffic apps and has all the necessary functions to implement synchronization, even for files.

But [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) looks like a very good alternative too. Maybe even better.